# Unable to configure Ubuntu kiosk mode 12.04

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, google-chrome, kiosk

[Setting Up Ubuntu as a Kiosk Web Appliance](http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/)
[How-to Ubuntu Kiosk](http://blogoless.blogspot.in/2015/06/how-to-ubuntu-kiosk.html?m=1)
[How to set up an Ubuntu Kiosk](http://www.techpository.com/linux-how-to-setup-a-ubuntu-kiosk/)
[Ubuntu Web Kiosk in 10 Easy Steps](http://nexxylove.tumblr.com/post/22690398464/ubuntu-web-kiosk-in-10-easy-steps)

I saw the websites above but I am unable configure kiosk mode.

I created `/usr/share/xsessions/kiosk.desktop` and `/usr/share/xessions/chromeKiosk.sh` files my user is going to autologin but it's unable to log in to chrome automatically

kiosk.desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
 Encoding=UTF-8
 Name=Kiosk Mode 
Comment=Chrome Kiosk Mode 
Exec=/usr/share/xsessions/chromeKiosk.sh
Type=Application
```

chromeKiosk.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
Xset  -dpms
Xset s off
openbox-session & 

while true; do 

rm –rf ~/.{caches}/google-chrome/ 
sed –i ‘s/Crashed/normal/g’ ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences google-chrome --start-maximized  http://{allowed-domain1.com} 

done
```

Answer (score 0):

I setup kiosks using the 14.04 server install.  I based my build on the instructions here - https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/ - I changed the program needed from Chrome which is very easy to do.

I chose this because the server install is very minimalist to start with so much less to break.  It lock the system into the program rather nicely.  You can get back to the terminal by hitting CTRL-ALT-F1 while restarting the application but you have to catch it just right!  Other than that I SSH into the machine to work on it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, removed or the site just stops working.  Therefore, please copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer (you can still use the link as the source of the material below your answer) **;-)**